# "The query contains more than one unnamed or duplicate field name" using SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
(select 
(case when CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), max(t1.Date), 103) = '01/01/1900' then '' else 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(24), max(dbo.UTC2BaseEntryWithDST(t1.Date,20,0)), 103)
END)as Date
from Table t0
inner join Table2 t1 on t1.ID = t0.ID)
```

but I'm getting an error in Report Builder

> the query contains more than one unnamed or duplicate field name, please specify unique column

How to put the "date" name at the end of the query? Thanks

Comment: Does this help? https://riptutorial.com/sql/example/1264/select-using-column-aliases

Comment: Hi @Quantumplate ,thank you for your advise , it is working when i add double quotes around the Date.

Comment: `case when CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), max(t1.Date), 103) = '01/01/1900'` is just silly, you should use an unambiguous date literal `case when max(t1.Date) = '19000101'` Also consider using `NULLIF` like this `NULLIF(max(t1.Date), '01/01/1900'))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put double quotes around the `Date` column name to have an alias that is also a key word in SQL (or uses special characters, such as spaces):

```
as "Date"
```

Comment: AFAIK, `date` is not a _reserved_ keyword in SQL Server. I.e. doesn't need to be delimited. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_reserved_words